# How to get Notified automatically once the node on selenium grid goes offline

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jasmine, grid, protractor

I have 4 nodes on the selenium grid and one of them goes offline and there is no way I know about the node going offline unless i go to the grid and check it myself.

Is there any way or any plug-in I can use to get notified once the node goes offline on the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You could install a custom servlet to your hub or/and nodes and let it notify something in your infrastructure to give a living sign.

```
public class CustomServlet extends RegistryBasedServlet {

public CustomServlet() {
    super(null);
    init();
}

public CustomServlet(Registry registry) {
    super(registry);
    init();
}

private void init() {

    //schedule a timer and send "im alive" somewhere
}
```

node-config.json(see selenium docs)

```
"servlets" :["CustomServlet"],
```

You also could ping the nodes from an external program/script every x and notify if there is not the expected responseCode